Demonic Possession or Something Fixable?
This is regarding a work PC, so I'm limited on what I can do to test/fix as an end user, but I'll be sharing this with our IT folks. We're just crowd sourcing solutions at this point, because it's gotten ridiculous.
My computer(s) are possessed. I'm currently using a brand new Dell PC with 64-bit Windows 11 Pro and a G3 MS tenant. My old PC had this same issue and it was replaced with the thought that this was a hardware issue - keyboard was glitching or something. But it's now occurring with the brand new machine, despite no crossover since I didn't need anything moved over from the old one (using exclusively OneDrive/cloud software/shared drives).
It will sporadically act as if someone is sitting here holding down the [ENTER] key. Today alone it inserted 288 blank PPT slides into a presentation I was working on, while I was turned away from my screen and not touching it and opened 26 new Excel docs and started adding hundreds of new rows to the last one it opened.
If I try to head to Teams to contact IT while this is happening, it'll let me type a single letter before mashing [Enter] and making it impossible to search for a contact.
On the old PC, it entered dozens of blank pages into a Word doc over the course of seconds. The only peripherals are a Logitech bluetooth mouse (and this happens whether I'm using it or not) and a Dell external monitor (which I've also tried not using and it doesn't impact).
Any ideas???

This question is about using a computer, not programming one, so it probably belongs on the Super User site instead of here.
